# How do I set up VS CODE PHP-DEBUG on a (Synology) NAS? / remote device

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, synology

Going round and around in circles on this one.

With a local install xampp setup I can get PHP-DEBUG working just fine in both standard modes:

1. "Listen for XDebug" and
2. "Launch currently open script"

Trying to move this to a remote machine - specifically a Synology NAS.

In VS Code, I can connect the folder via a standard SMB path, e.g.:

```
//[nas]/web/[project]
```

In localhosts I have mapping to the site and this is managed via virtualhost in Synology DiskStation and this works fine, e.g.

```
10.x.y.z dev.mysite.com
```

I'm trying all manner of things suggested on setting hostname, pathmappings, xdebug.remote_host (set to NAS IP), xdebug.idekey (VSCODE), xdebug.remote_connect_back (ON) etc but really not getting anywhere- latest dead end is an error:

```
message: 'listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 10.x.y.z:9001'
```

NB - Using port 9001 to avoid conflict elsewhere...

launch.json as below - where am I going wrong?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "dev.mysite.com",
            "port": 9001,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/": "${workspaceFolder}"
              },
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "hostname": "dev.mysite.com",
            "port": 9001,
            "pathMappings": {
                "//[nas]/web/[project]": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "log": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Help.....

Answer (score 1):

> "xdebug.remote_host (set to NAS IP),"

**No.** That is always wrong. The `xdebug.remote_host` (now `xdebug.client_host` in Xdebug 3) needs to point to the machine where your IDE runs at. It is *Xdebug* that makes the connection.

Also, these settings do nothing for Xdebug 3, which is the latest (and only supported) version. Please read the [Upgrade Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense.
I have made the suggested change but this has not resolved the issue unfortunately.
Limited ability to upgrade PHP / xDebug etc whilst working with a Synology where the parts are all in packages.
I could try to go down the Docker route for a more controllable Apache / PHP / xdebug env, but would prefer not to as this is a hobbyist / dev setup for me and my son so we're at the limits of our technical capability here.
Cheers

Comment: @MIkFo 1) Update your question with the actual config (your Xdebug settings from php.ini + whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output -- must be captured in the same way as you are trying to debug: a CLI or web page) 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say (if it tries to connect at all, where and what the response is). 3) If it tries but fails/no response -- either wrong IP:port .. or firewall (NAS or your target PC).

Comment: So the issue with the PORT was the same (similar) to the `xdebug.remote_host` pointed out by @Derick 
There was no conflict on the _client_ on port 9000 but there _was_ on 9001 (ntoskrnl.exe) 
Shifted back to port 9000 and all I need to do now is fix the pathmappings.
Getting there!
Thanks,